# Nginx not serve media files

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I develop an application with Django and Angular 4, before I can see media files without problems in my localhost, but in my LightSailServer I delete my sock file created with gunicorn and deploy my app again, but I don't understand why I don't see my media files in this moment, this is my nginx file, but I don't touch this in all moment, I think my problem is in other way, any ideas?

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 54.12.12.142;

location = /favicon.ico {
    alias /home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/favicon.ico;
}
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer;
}
location /media/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/media/;
}
location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/trackerServer.sock;
}
}
```

I don't see problems in this file, but I can't see my media files and these exists!
PD: I obtain correct path to media files from my web server, only I can't see these.

This I have in my `settings.py`

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static-root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Thanks

**SOLVED**
I had deleted the image folder from my server

Comment: did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` to generate the static files?

Comment: After hosting  did you change your media and static files URL in settings.py ??

Comment: @TarunLalwani but collectstatic it's okay, return this `0 static files copied to '/home/ubuntu/tracker-web/static-root', 73 unmodified.` and @Akash, only change `DEBUG = True`, but in this moment `DEBUG = False`

Comment: You message says the files are generated in `/home/ubuntu/tracker-web/static-root` and you are trying to serve them from `/home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/static` in your nginx config?

Comment: I attach my nginx config in my question, but in my settings.py I have this `STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static-root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]`

Comment: Is it the `media` files or the `static` files or both that aren't served?

Comment: as @TarunLalwani says, your nginx config for the location `/static/` should point to `/home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/static-root` since that is where your static files are collected.

Comment: @dirkgroten Only media files, I suppose no problems with static files because I can see my js and css. This is my page http://54.175.253.151 if you want see my errors in Inspector browser. before I can see these photos.

Comment: This isn't a forum. If this is solved, please write an answer and mark it correct, don't write `[SOLVED]` in the title.

Comment: @Soviut now??? thanks!